# How to improve ScrollView perfomance?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a scrollView that works very slow. Inside this ScrollView I have fragments with custom UI. I am adding fragments with FragmentTransactions. How can i improve ScrollView perfomance. I consider that using fragments inside ScrollView is not the best choice? What  do you think.

Here is my ScrollView in main_activity.xml

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="145dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingEnd="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amount"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="202dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amount">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/first_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/second_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/third_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fourth_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="360dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fifth_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="480dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/sixth_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="600dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/seventh_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="720dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/eighth_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="840dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/ninth_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="960dp" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/tenth_business"
            android:name="stoppandemic.emptymindgames.com.HospitalFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="283dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1080dp" />


    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is my FragmentClass

```
public class HospitalFragment extends Fragment {


public onImageClickListener mCallBack;

public final static String TAG = "ArtemyDebugger";

private int mTime;
private int mAmountOfProduction;
private int mPrice;
private int mId;
private int mMultiplier;
private int MultiplierPeople;

private View view;
OneBusinesBinding binding;

public HospitalFragment() {
}

public void setmHospital(Hospital hospital) {
    this.mTime = hospital.getTime();
    this.mAmountOfProduction = hospital.getAmount();
    this.mPrice = hospital.getPrice();
    this.mId = hospital.getId();
    this.mMultiplier = hospital.getMultiplier();
    this.MultiplierPeople = hospital.getMultiplierPeople();
}

public interface onImageClickListener {
    void clickOnImage(int id);

    void onTextViewOfPriceSelected(int id, int amountOfProduction, int price, int time, int multiplier);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        mCallBack = (onImageClickListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnImageClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.one_busines, container, false);
    view = binding.getRoot();
    binding.imageBusiness.setImageResource(AndroidImageAssets.getPictures().get(mId));
    binding.amountofProduction.setText(getString(R.string.amount_of_production, mAmountOfProduction));
    binding.price.setText(getString(AssetsUpgradeStrings.getStrings_On_Button_Buy().get(mId), convertNumberToString(mPrice)));
    binding.progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
    ;
    binding.nameHospital.setText(AssetsUpgradeStrings.getHospitalsNames().get(mId));
    binding.textViewOnProgressbar.setText(getString(R.string.string_on_progressbar, mTime));
    binding.imageBusiness.setOnClickListener((v) -> {

        mCallBack.clickOnImage(mId);
    });
    binding.price.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        if (MainActivity.mAllMoney >= mPrice) {

            mAmountOfProduction++;
            MainActivity.mAllMoney -= mPrice;
            mPrice = (int) Math.ceil(MyConstants.getPrices().get(mId) * Math.pow(1.12, mAmountOfProduction));
            mCallBack.onTextViewOfPriceSelected(mId, mAmountOfProduction, mPrice, mTime, mMultiplier);
            binding.price.setText(getString(AssetsUpgradeStrings.getStrings_On_Button_Buy().get(mId), convertNumberToString(mPrice)));
            binding.amountofProduction.setText(getString(R.string.amount_of_production, mAmountOfProduction));
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
HospitalFragment firstHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment secondHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment thirdHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment fourthHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment fifthHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment sixthHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment seventhHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment eighthHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment ninthHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
    HospitalFragment tenthHospitalFragment = new HospitalFragment();
     firstHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(0));
    secondHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(1));
    thirdHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(2));
    fourthHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(3));
    fifthHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(4));
    sixthHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(5));
    seventhHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(6));
    eighthHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(7));
    ninthHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(8));
    tenthHospitalFragment.setmHospital(mListHospitals.get(9));

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.first_business, firstHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.second_business, secondHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.third_business, thirdHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.fourth_business, fourthHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.fifth_business, fifthHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.sixth_business, sixthHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.seventh_business, seventhHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.eighth_business, eighthHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.ninth_business, ninthHospitalFragment)
            .replace(R.id.tenth_business, tenthHospitalFragment)
            .commit();
```

Comment: This feels like something that would be handled better by `RecyclerView`. Beyond that, what exactly do you mean by "works very slow"?

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  I just wanna make productive and speed better. On older devices it works worse that i wanted. When i scroll, it does not work perfect, a litle bit slowly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first part of your question (How to improve scrollView) check the following link (AndroidDeveloper scrollView documentation), where you'll find all the information on how to improve your scrollView, and make it smoother

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView

As for the second part of your question, no, nested scrollView is not a good practice, I suggest you take a look at the following thread for further details

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/298kyx/fragments_inside_a_scrollview/

Hope this helps! If not then I'm sorry I couldn't be much of a help, maybe you can try editing your question to make it clearer. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot)) if i undestand you correctly i have to look at RecyclerView vert closely)

Comment: yes, glad I helped :) if this answers your question please approve it. Cheers!